# convergence radius and sum of a series

Tags: complex-analysis

1) Given $S(z)$ find the radius of convergence and sum.

$$S(z)= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(4z-2)^n}{n}$$

Then:

$$S(z)= \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(4z-2)^n}{n} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{4^n(z-\frac{1}{2})^n}{n}=\sum_{n \geq 1}a_n(z-\frac{1}{2}) \Longrightarrow R=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|)^{-1}=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$S'(z)=\sum_{n \geq 1}4^n(z-\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}=4\sum_{n \geq 1}(4z-2)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-(4z-2)}=\frac{1}{3-4z}$$

$$ S(z)=\int{\frac{1}{3-4z}}=-\log(3-4z)+C $$

Now I need to properly define the logarithm ini question.

Let $f(z)=\log(z)$ and $g(z)=3-4z$, since $f^{-1}((-\infty,0])=[\frac{3}{4},\infty)$ then $f(z)$ is holomorphic in the disk of convergence by chosing $(-\infty,0]$ as a branch cut.

However I'm not sure how to deal with the constant $C$ nor which determination of the argument I should pick for the logarithm.

This is what I managed:

By definition $f(z)=\log(z)=\log|z| + i \arg (z)$ so:

$$S(z)=\log(3-4z)+C=\log|3-4z|+ i\arg(z)+C$$

$$z \in \mathbb{R} \Longrightarrow \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(4z-2)^n}{n} \in \mathbb{R} \Longrightarrow \log|3-4z|+ i\arg(z)+C \in \mathbb{R} \Longrightarrow i\arg(z)+C \in \mathbb{R}$$

So either $i\arg(z)=0, C \in \mathbb{R}$ or $C \in \mathbb{C}, i\arg(z)+C=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am a naive proto-mathematician,
so I would argue like this:

Since
$-\ln(1-x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}
$
converges unconditionally
for $|x| < 1$,
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(4z-2)^n}{n}
=-\ln(1-(4z-2))
=-\ln(3-4z)
$
and this converges for
$|4z-2| < 1$
or
$|z-\frac12| < \frac14
$.